# Session state service failed- UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, prism, unhandled-exception, desktop-bridge

I am building a UWP application, also i am using desktop bridge which allows the UWP app to launch a win32 application and to communicate with it, to process some data that the UWP app can't give me its result.
The usual behavior of the is that the win32 app is launched for the UWP app, it process the data and then send the response to the UWP app and then it closes.

If for some reason the win32 app opens mutiple times in row, the UWP app crashes(it disappears) when i try to reopen the app, for example while debugging, it takes me to the App.g.i.cs, and say that there is a Session state service failed exception.

For some research i saw that this exception is related to prism, but i explained the behavior above in case it will have any effect on this exception.
Is it possible to know what is the source of this exception so we may able to handle it?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to answer this. It would be best if you could provide a minimal code repro.

If I had to take a guess, I would say your UWP isn't handling the multiple AppService connection requests from the Win32 processes. You may want to review that code and make sure you are robust against multiple Win32's connecting to your UWP. Alternatively, you could look into making your Win32 process a singleton - this way you would prevent multiple instances in the first place.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT First of all i want to thank you for highlighting making the Win32 process as a singleton. I will definitely look into it. But on another hand, i believe the session state exception is not only related to this. I only highlighted it so if someone with previous experience may try to link them together. But this exception is related to prism and UI, because sometimes it crashes without the case of the Win32 process. So in a random behavior the application may crash and next time i open the application it shows me the unhandled exception which is the session state service failed.